# Vectorize Pytorch Tensor Indexing Operation

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize an operation in PyTorch, but I'm not sure how to do it. This is the code using for loops right now. 'm' is a dictionary with int keys and a 1d tensor as value.
The output mask is 2d. L is the number of layers, this loop is probably necessary. I am therefore looking to mostly replace the 2 inner loops. I was thinking of using torch.gather somehow, but without success

```
for l in range(L):
    mask = torch.zeros((m[l].shape[0], m[l-1].shape[0]))
    for i in range(m[l].shape[0]):
        for j in range(m[l-1].shape[0]):
            mask[i,j] = R[m[l-1][j], m[l][i]]
    masks.append(mask)
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer myself. One can use numpy advanced indexing as described here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

It then comes down to the following

```
for l in range(L):
    mask = R[m[l-1], m[l][:, np.newaxis]]
    masks.append(mask)
```

np.newaxis makes sure that the colum index is repeated for each row.